# Points around points on curve

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have this curve where I've sampled points on, then with a Sample Curve node I used the tangent and normal information to place instances oriented the right way on this curve. Now I want to place points around each of these instances and orient them with the same normal and tangent.

I don't know how to get the second set of points around each one of the first set of points. That the displacement of each second set points is identical with relation to each other is not a problem.

This what I've managed so far:

[image]

We have the green buckets that are placed around the curve and a single set of instances nearby which I want to replace by the group of points provided by the set of points in the center.

And these are my Geometry nodes:

[image]

Plus some nodes off-screen that facilitate the movement of the buckets, but that's not important for now.

The "Content" group is placing those single set of instances above the buckets that I want to replace by the points from the "Content-Spread" group.

What would be the easiest way to place those 15 points at the position of each *Content* instance?

Here's my blend file:
[image]

Comment: to attract more people to your question i recommend providing a blend file so we don't have to rebuild everything manually. You want help right? so i would - if i were you - make it as easy as possible for those people, who are willing to answer you for free in their spare time...

Comment: Sure thing! I removed all unnecessary stuff from the project and uploaded it. See the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am really not sure what you mean, but hopefully this (if not, please add a sketch or picture how it should look like):

[image]

result:

[image]

what i did, is just distributing points on faces after realize instances on a grid, which i just added as instance as you added the other instances.

i just hope that helps.

Comment: I can work from that. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome!